# XSLT Copy, Trim, Sort and Delete in one transform

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, namespaces, trim

I have the following XML.

```
<oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/">
    <dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xml:lang="hrv">Naslov rada</dc:title>
    <dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">2001-01-01</dc:date>
    <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Prezime, Ime</dc:creator>
    <dc:date xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">2002-02-02</dc:date>
    <dc:relation xml:lang="eng">University of Zagreb. Academy of dramatic art. </dc:relation>
</oai_dc:dc>
```

and the output that I need is this:

```
<dc>
    <creator>Prezime, Ime</creator>
    <date>2002-02-02</date> 
    <relation lang="eng">University of Zagreb. Academy of dramatic art.</relation>
    <title lang="hrv">Naslov rada</title>   
</dc>
```

So, what I need to do is: Remove namespaces from attributes and elements. I tried that with this code and it works.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
 <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Next I need to sort elements by element name (and maybe by attribute name). I did that with this code and it works.

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
    <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Then I need to delete all  elements that starts with "2001". I did that with this and it works.

```
<xsl:template match="/dc/date[starts-with(text(), '2001')]" />
```

And finally, I have to trim all text values in elements. Notice:

```
<dc:relation xml:lang="eng">University of Zagreb. Academy of dramatic art. </dc:relation>
```

I should trim white space from end (and begining), so it's:

```
<dc:relation xml:lang="eng">University of Zagreb. Academy of dramatic art.</dc:relation>
```

So my problem is that I can't make it work in one XSLT combined. Idea is to: Remove prefixes (namespaces) from elements and attributes that define namespaces, then sort elements and delete some specific elements (like  in my case), and finally trim all remaining text values.

I did all this but with more then one transforms. Is it possible to do it in one go?

I can only use XSLT 1.0

Comment: You don't want to remove the `xml:` prefix on the `xml:lang` attribute, any attributes with an `xml:` prefix have special meaning in XML. Also, minor point but you're input XML isn't valid, it's missing an `xmlns:dc` declaration on the `dc:relation` element. It's obvious what it's supposed to be though, but it should fail any XML parser like that.

Comment: Yes, that relation element should have dc declared for valid xml. Tnx for notice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
      <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
      <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
 <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/oai_dc:dc/dc:date[starts-with(text(), '2001')]" />

<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

creates the output (http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvB)

```
<dc>
   <creator>Prezime, Ime</creator>
   <date>2002-02-02</date>
   <relation lang="eng">University of Zagreb. Academy of dramatic art.</relation>
   <title lang="hrv">Naslov rada</title>
</dc>
```

Note that the use of `normalize-space()` does not only trim leading and trailing white space but also replaces any sequences of white space between other characters to a single space.

Comment: Minor point, but `xml:lang` shouldn't have the prefix removed. I know that's what the OP asked for, but as I'm sure you're aware, `xml:` attributes have special meaning.

Comment: @Flynn1179, I understand your concern, but namespaces have a meaning too, so I think if someone wants to strip namespaces then stripping the predefined `xml:` prefix is within the task specified.

Comment: Yes, there is difference between xml: and xmlns:, but at this point my goal was to reduce 2 xmls to minimum, for simple comparation (string comparation) without iterating trough each node and attribute. This solution works beautiful for me! Ty!